# initializing a vector based on a 2d array

Tags: c++

I have a Visual Studio 2008 C++03 application where I would like to initialize a std::vector based on a two dimensional array.

For example:

```
#define DATA_SIZE 6

struct Data
{
    UINT a;
    BYTE b;
    BYTE c;
    BYTE d;

    Data()
        : /* initialize all members to 0*/
    {
    };

    explicit Data( const BYTE data[ DATA_SIZE ] )
        : a( data[ 0 ] << 16 | data[ 1 ] << 8 | data[ 2 ] ),
          b( data[ 3 ] ),
          c( data[ 4 ] ),
          d( data[ 5 ] )
    {
    };
};

inline bool operator==( const Data& lhs, const Data& rhs )
{
    return /* true if all members are equal */
};

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
    const BYTE source[][ DATA_SIZE ] = 
    {
        { 0x01, 0xfe, 0xaa, 0x01, 0xcc, 0x13 },
        { 0x02, 0xa1, 0x02, 0xbb, 0x02, 0xdd }
    }

    // how should this be done?
    std::vector< Data > data_list( source[ 0 ], source[ countof( source) - 1 ] );

    ASSERT( data_list[ 0 ] == Data( source[ 0 ] ) );
    ASSERT( data_list[ 1 ] == Data( source[ 1 ] ) );
    return 0;
}
```

Is there a way to do this without a `for` loop iterating through each item in the `data` array and calling `push_back`?

Comment: @ildjarn - edited to make that clearer.

Comment: If you removed the `explicit` keyword would that not allow the compiler to implicitly convert the BYTE arrays to Data objects?

Comment: If you used `std::tr1::array<BYTE, N>` instead of raw C-arrays, this would be completely trivial.

Comment: @Dennis - it would, but that wouldn't help.

Comment: Note that `const BYTE data[ DATA_SIZE ]` is equivalent to `BYTE const*`.  The `DATA_SIZE` here has no effect and thus should be omitted.

Comment: @JamesMcNellis - You don't feel it serves a purpose to tell the user of the API the expected size of the array?

Comment: @ildjarn - `boost::array` is acceptable to me. But, I'm not seeing how that would work. Can you point to an example of what you're referring to?

Comment: @PaulH:  No, absolutely not.  It would be far better to have the constructor take a first/last range and assert in the constructor that the size of the range is the correct size, or have it take an `array<BYTE, DATA_SIZE>`, possibly by `const&`.  The use of `DATA_SIZE` in the declaration gives a false sense of security, as there is no requirement that the provided pointer point to an array of that size.

Comment: @JamesMcNellis - would you be happy with `explicit Data( const BYTE (&data) [DATA_SIZE] )`?

Comment: @Robᵩ:  That would be an improvement, yes, though it rather limits usage of the constructor (e.g., it then becomes difficult to call it with dynamically allocated arrays without contorted casts).  (Of course, one could always provide more than one constructor, and that one would potentially be useful.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an approach using [Boost.Array](http://www.boost.org/libs/array/):

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <cassert>
#include <vector>
#include <boost/array.hpp>

typedef unsigned UINT;
typedef unsigned char BYTE;

std::size_t const DATA_SIZE = 6;

struct Data
{
    UINT a;
    BYTE b, c, d;

    Data() : a(), b(), c(), d() { }

    Data(boost::array<BYTE, DATA_SIZE> const& data)
      : a(data[0] << 16 | data[1] << 8 | data[2]),
        b(data[3]),
        c(data[4]),
        d(data[5])
    { }
};

inline bool operator ==(Data const& lhs, Data const& rhs)
{
    return lhs.a == rhs.a
        && lhs.b == rhs.b
        && lhs.c == rhs.c
        && lhs.d == rhs.d;
}

int main()
{
    boost::array<boost::array<BYTE, DATA_SIZE>, 2> const source =
    {{
        {{ 0x01, 0xfe, 0xaa, 0x01, 0xcc, 0x13 }},
        {{ 0x02, 0xa1, 0x02, 0xbb, 0x02, 0xdd }}
    }};

    std::vector<Data> data_list(source.begin(), source.end());

    assert(data_list[0] == Data(source[0]));
    assert(data_list[1] == Data(source[1]));
}
```

[Online demo](http://ideone.com/IObyG).

Answer (score 3):

The least change you could make is:

```
std::vector< Data > data_list(
  &source[ 0 ],
  &source[ countof( source) ] );
```